# Subtract fixed row value in reference to column value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, subtraction

I would like to subtract a fixed row value in rows, in reference to their values in another column.

**My data looks like this:**

```
       TRACK    TIME  POSITION_X
0        1        0       12       
1        1        30      13       
2        1        60      15       
3        1        90      11      
4        2         0      10     
5        2        20      11
6        2        60      13
7        2        90      17
```

**I would like to subtract a fixed row value (WHEN TIME=0) of the POSITION_X column in reference to the TRACK column, and create a new column ("NEW_POSX") with those values. The output should be like this:**

```
       TRACK    TIME  POSITION_X   NEW_POSX
0        1        0       12         0   
1        1        30      13         1
2        1        60      15         3
3        1        90      11        -1
4        2         0      10         0
5        2        20      11         1
6        2        60      13         3
7        2        90      17         7
```

I have been using the following code to get this done:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'TRACK':  [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
        'TIME': [0,30,60,90,0,20,60,90],
        'POSITION_X': [12,13,15,11,10,11,13,17],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['TRACK','TIME','POSITION_X'])
df['NEW_POSX']= df.groupby('TRACK')['POSITION_X'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
df.head(8)
```

... but I don't get the desired output. Instead, I get a new column where every row is subtracted by the previous row (according to the "TRACK" column):

```
       TRACK    TIME  POSITION_X   NEW_POSX
0        1        0       12         0   
1        1        30      13         1
2        1        60      15         2
3        1        90      11        -4
4        2         0      10         0
5        2        20      11         1
6        2        60      13         2
7        2        90      17         4
```

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` and `first` to get the value at time 0, and then substract it to the `'POSITION_X'` column:

```
s=df.groupby('TRACK')['POSITION_X'].transform('first')
df['NEW_POSX']=df['POSITION_X']-s

#Same as: 
#df['NEW_POSX']=df['POSITION_X'].sub(s)
```

Output:

```
df
   TRACK  TIME  POSITION_X  NEW_POSX
0      1     0          12         0
1      1    30          13         1
2      1    60          15         3
3      1    90          11        -1
4      2     0          10         0
5      2    20          11         1
6      2    60          13         3
7      2    90          17         7
```

Comment: Your welcome! Please, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) and upvoting the answer if it was helpful! :) @FabianaRossi